# binding mysql database to dropdown list vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need help binding MySQL database to a dropdown list.

here's how I usually connect to the database

```
Dim connectionstring As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBstring").ConnectionString
Dim connectme As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(connectionstring)
Dim ODBCdataset As DataSet = New DataSet()
Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * FROM treconcalculation WHERE fid = " & Request.QueryString("id")
connectme.Open()
Dim ODBCdataadapter As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(sqlquery, connectme)
ODBCdataadapter.Fill(ODBCdataset, "treconcalculation")
connectme.Close()

            make1 = ODBCdataset.Tables("treconcalculation").Rows(0).Item(1)
            model1 = ODBCdataset.Tables("treconcalculation").Rows(0).Item(2)
            cc1 = ODBCdataset.Tables("treconcalculation").Rows(0).Item(3)
            below2 = ODBCdataset.Tables("treconcalculation").Rows(0).Item(4)
            below3 = ODBCdataset.Tables("treconcalculation").Rows(0).Item(5)
            below4 = ODBCdataset.Tables("treconcalculation").Rows(0).Item(6)
            below5 = ODBCdataset.Tables("treconcalculation").Rows(0).Item(7)
            above5 = ODBCdataset.Tables("treconcalculation").Rows(0).Item(8)
```

how do I go about implementing it to a dropdown list? I've tried

```
Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBstring").ConnectionString
            Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT fid, fmake, fmodel FROM treconcalculation")
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim ds As New DataSet()
                        sda.Fill(ds)
                        vehicle1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                        vehicle1.DataTextField = "fmodel"
                        vehicle1.DataValueField = "fid"
                        vehicle1.DataBind()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            vehicle1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select Customer--", "0"))
```

and an error comes up saying Keyword not supported: 'driver'.

THanks

Comment: which line gives you that error?

Comment: I found out that this line made the problem. connectionString="DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver} is it possible to change the script to ODBC driver?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is not with the DropDown binding: it's with the connection string, that you are using to connect to the database: I request you to *check whether the ODBC Driver 3.51 is installed on your machine* and also check the connection string having all valid parameters. If you are building connection string in the code i suggest you to use like the following:

```
Dim _DbHost = "localhost";
Dim _DbName = "yourDBName";
Dim _DbPassWord = "DbUser";
Dim _DbUser = "*****";
Dim ConString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" +
                "Server=" + DbHost + ";" +
                "Database=" + DbName + ";" +
                "User=" + DbUser + ";" +
                "Password=" + DbPassWord + ";" +
                "option=3;"
```